# Ontario HST rebate: Do common-law couples qualify for the couples (family) rebate?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, rebate, common-law-marriage

Do common-law couples qualify for the couples rebate?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.** Refer to the Ontario Ministry of Revenue's FAQ titled [Who qualifies as a family?](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/faq_eligibility.html#Q15)  Quote:

> **Who qualifies as a family?**
>
> Married couples **or common-law
>   partners (with or without children)**
>   and single parents will qualify as
>   families.  *[emphasis mine]*

Of course, you ought to have filed your income tax returns to reflect such status.